# How to 'record' a trip - places I visited?

Tags: gps, gps-tracking, maps

I am going for a trip for 3 weeks and I want to record all the places I visited using my Android mobile.

I most likely I won't have data connectivity - only GPS. If I don't find anything else I will use [Endomondo](http://www.endomondo.com/), but I'm open to other solutions, including third-party apps (preferably free).

I am using an HTC One XL running CyanogenMod 10.

Comment: This question, being of the _"Can you suggest an app that does X?"_ kind, is off-topic here, please read the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions) for more details

Comment: @Francisco: OK, could you suggest what I can do to find some answers in here except the search?

Comment: You should rephrase your question so that it is about the application you use to record the sites you visit, for example you mention **Endomondo**: so if you ask a question about how to use this app or about any specific difficulty you're having with it, then it will be valid here. In short, try to be more specific with what you ask for you to get better answers. A question asking for recommendations of apps tends to get very subjective answers, and that's not the idea here. Good luck with your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is [Google's My Tracks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks&hl=en)

Follow the link and see the features yourself. Everyhing you want is there. And the best part is it's free!!

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 I've been using My Tracks for few months now. Quite simple and fulfills my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Trip Jounal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iqapps.mobile.tripjournalfull).
It records your gps track log and combines photos/videos/notes you've made along the way and can display it all on a map.

Comment: Looks good but it's not free and last update was like half an year ago. Also users reviews are not so promising...