# New Android maps - how to show navigation without destination

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, navigation

Older version of Google Maps for android had a separate Navigation app, in it I could either set a destination for guided navigation or simple select "Display map" with would always show my GPS location as I travel (streets, turns etc.)

With recently updated map app, I can either see my static location on the map or choose destination for navigation.

How do I simple display dynamic navigation map that would display my current location as I drive?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50353/23379)

Comment: @Sid, that didn't exactly answer my question. I didn't lose Navigation app. I lost ability see my current dynamic location without setting up the destination, I commented your other answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, upon further research I found that "Follow me" feature or "Navigation without destination set" was removed from the latest release of Android map app.

Following someone else's advice I am switching (at least for now). to the Waze app

Answer (score 2):

You just need to access "[My Location](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3137748?ref_topic=3137684)" in Maps.

Click the "location" button [image] in the bottom right corner to have the map scroll to your location. (Obviously you need to have Location Services turned on.) The button will turn blue and there will be a glowing blue dot at your location.

Tap the button again and the view will change to "[compass mode](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/2839801?ref_topic=3137684)", a partial-3d view with 3-d building outlines and pointed in the direction you're facing. The button will change to a compass. Tap again to get back to the top-down view.

Comment: If you want something to keep track of where you travel, the recent overhaul to [MyTracks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks) looks pretty good.

Comment: I did try that and it does show my static location, but it doesn't show street movement same way Navigation does when direction is set. Old app used to do that. So am I correct in assuming this is no longer available?

Comment: @Yuriy: I guess I'm not clear on what you mean. When I'm looking at the map, if I'm in motion my position on the map changes.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter touch that icon three times and strat the trip. Are you telling about [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/36278/23379) Al Everett?

Comment: @Sid: No, I'm talking about Google Maps. MyTracks is a separate app.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Ya ya. I know. the latter part of the comment was to Al Everett. :D You **should be** able to get your *rynamic location* with three and/or two touches to that `target` icon.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. I just googled (no pan intended) a bit on my own (http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/kRm9Tfvmp2k) and found that the "follow me" navigation is indeed M.I.A. after the update. Guess I will have to downgrade to get this back.

Answer (score -1):

To activate the Drive mode, do these steps:

1. Navigate to the home screen
2. Long tap on an empty spot
3. Choose "Add widget"
4. Select "Google Maps"
5. Select "Drive Mode"
6. Add it to the home screen

Comment: This answer seems to work for me. To use it, I leave it on the Set Destination screen but swipe down on the proposed locations list to minimize it. The screen stays on and the blue dot follows my location as I move.